# eBay API returns "GeteBayTime" is invalid or not supported in this release

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

This is my first test with the eBay's API.
I'm attaching the code I am using and it gives me the following error:

> 2016-02-13 11:10:22FailureUnsupported API call.The API call "GeteBayTime" is invalid or not supported in this release.2ErrorRequestError92117790382

Code:

```
$EndPoint='https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll';

$header= array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml',
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 921',
    'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: ' . $devId,
    'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: ' . $appId,
    'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: ' . $certId,
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: ' . 'GeteBayTime',
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: ' . '101',
    'X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING:XML'
);

$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GeteBayTimeRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
</GeteBayTimeRequest>';

$connection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, $EndPoint);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($connection);
curl_close($connection);
echo $response;
```

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the Trading operation is called [GeteBayOfficalTime](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GeteBayOfficialTime.html) not GeteBayTime. Replacing GeteBayTime with GeteBayOfficalTime in your code will make it work. In addition because you are calling a Trading operation you will need to add your eBay auth token to the API request.

```
$devId = '<DEV ID>';
$appId = '<APP ID>';
$certId = '<CERT ID>';
$authToken = '<AUTH TOKEN>';
$endPoint = 'https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll';

$header = [
    'Content-Type: text/xml',
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:921',
    "X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME:$devId",
    "X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME:$appId",
    "X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME:$certId",
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:GeteBayOfficialTime',
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID:101',
    'X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING:XML'
];

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GeteBayOfficialTimeRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <eBayAuthToken>$authToken</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
</GeteBayOfficialTimeRequest>
XML;

$connection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, $endPoint);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($connection);
curl_close($connection);
echo $response;
```

In case you're interested I have developed an [SDK for PHP](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php). The example below shows how to use the SDK to call GeteBayOfficalTime. There are more [examples available](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples)

```
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Constants;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Services;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types;

$service = new Services\TradingService([
    'apiVersion' => 921
    'siteId'     => Constants\SiteIds::IT,
    'sandbox'    => true
]);

$request = new Types\GeteBayOfficialTimeRequestType();
$request->RequesterCredentials = new Types\CustomSecurityHeaderType();
$request->RequesterCredentials->eBayAuthToken = $authToken;

$response = $service->geteBayOfficialTime($request);

if ($response->Ack !== 'Success') {
    if (isset($response->Errors)) {
        foreach ($response->Errors as $error) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", $error->ShortMessage);
        }
    }
} else {
    printf("The official eBay time is: %s\n", $response->Timestamp->format('H:i (\G\M\T) \o\n l jS F Y'));
}
```